# Following the output of the overline character and the use of endl, cout doesn't print characters anymore

Tags: c++, windows, character-encoding, stream, windows-console

I don't understand why the "a" isn't printed when executing the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, 100);
    std::cout << "‾";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a";
    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* I changed the font in my Windows console to "Consolas" for the overline character to be shown correctly. My Windows version is Windows 7 Enterprise (Service Pack 1).

I thought that the behavior should be the same as the following code, which correctly prints the "a":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, 100);
    std::cout << "‾\n";
    fflush(stdout);
    std::cout << "a";
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs I get, respectively:

[image] [image]

The command line of how my first example gets compiled in Code::Blocks 16.01:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, the info that you give here is not sufficient to help.  First, does the overline character print well (to eliminate possible inconsistencies where the compiler would not understant your source code litteral to be UTF8 ? Then have you tried to output an endl at the end, to eliminate some buffering issues ?

Comment: @Christophe Hi! I added screenshots of the outputs I get. Yes, the overline character prints well and yes, I have tried outputing an 'endl' at the end, but it changed nothing.

Comment: Windows version? Compiler toolset? You should know that UNICODE support in `cmd.exe` is broken in many ways. There are attempts to fix it, though: [Windows Command-Line: Unicode and UTF-8 Output Text Buffer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/11/15/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/)

Comment: @Swordfish My Windows version is Windows 7 Enterprise (Service Pack 1) and I am using the GNU GCC Compiler in Code::Blocks 16.01. I added a screenshot of my compiler settings. Thank you for the link, I'll have a look at it!

Comment: *I am using the GNU GCC Compiler* – MinGW or mingw-64? – *I added a screenshot of my compiler settings.* – The command line of how your example gets compiled would have been more helpful.

Comment: @Swordfish, a console application has nothing to do with the CMD shell. That's a shell that simply uses a console (i.e. instance of conhost.exe), exactly like any other console app. Actually, CMD is a Unicode-enabled application and uses the console's wide-character Unicode API -- since it was released in 1993. The console itself supports most of the 16-bit basic multilingual plane, except it doesn't support complex scripts (e.g. Arabic). But using its legacy codepage API with UTF-8 is broken in many ways, especially prior to Windows 8, and for input still so even in Windows 10.

Comment: @Swordfish I changed my screenshot for the command line of how my first example gets compiled. Hopefully that's more useful information. :)

Comment: Would you please just stop posting screenshots of TEXT!?

Comment: If you print this as UTF-8, e.g. `"\xe2\x80\xbe\r\n"`, in Windows 7 the console (via WINAPI `WriteFile` or `WriteConsoleA`)  mistakenly returns the number of decoded wide characters to the caller. So 5 bytes were written, but the CRT thinks only 3 were written. So it writes the final two again, i.e. `"\r\n"`. Notice the extra line in your 2nd screenshot. I'd have to examine the first `cout` case in a debugger. I don't recall off the top of my head how MinGW's C++ runtime behaves in this case. Either way, using UTF-8 with the console is a dead-in-the-water design. Use the wide-character API.